# For a rational function which one of the following is true?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b,c,d$ be rational numbers with $ad-bc \ne 0$ then the function

$f : \mathbb{Q^c} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{ax +b}{cx +d}$ is

(a) onto but not one one

(b) one to one but not onto

(c) neither one to one nor onto

(d) both on to one and onto.

Differentiating the function we get : $f'(x) = \dfrac{ad - bc}{(cx +d )^2}$. Since $ad - bc \ne 0$ either $ad -bc \gt 0$ or $ad -bc \lt 0$

Hence , $f(x)$ is monotonic thus it is one - one.

Now if we take $c= 0 , d= a =1 , b =0$

$f(x) = x$ , So the range set is only $\mathbb{Q^c}$ and thus $f$ is not onto.

Hence (b) must be correct choice .

Is my answer correct ?

Comment: What is $\mathbb Q^c$?

Comment: @MattSamuel Most likely the complement of the set of rationals, i.e. the set of irrational real numbers.

Comment: Be careful applying "$f'(x)>0\implies f$ is one-to-one" on a function with singularities. $x-\frac1x$ has strictly positive derivative, but it's decidedly _not_ one-to-one.

Comment: @MattSamuel $\mathbb{Q^c}$ is the set of irrationals.

Comment: @Arthur: I think the function will have no singularity , the points of singularity are rational while domain is set of irrationals.

Comment: Take a look at my example function again. That one also only has a singularity at a rational value, but my point still stands: it is not one-to-one, even as a function defined on only the irrationals, and it is the singularity that allows this. The fact that the singularity happens at a rational point is rather irrelevant.

Comment: @zero But you can't take the derivative without considering the rationals as well, where there is a singularity. $x-1/x$ doesn't have a singularity in the irrational numbers either.

Comment: @MattSamuel : Yes , you are right  well how should I  proceed to solve this question ?

Comment: @zero You should be able to actually solve for the inverse function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need derivatives to check the homographic function $\bar f:\mathbf R\smallsetminus\bigl\{-\frac dc\bigr\}\longrightarrow\mathbf R\smallsetminus\bigl\{\frac ac\bigr\}\,$ defined by the same formula, is monotonic if $ad-bc\ne 0$ (actually increasing if $ad-bc>0$, decreasing if $ad-bc <0$).

Therefore, its restriction $f$ to $\mathbf Q^c$ is also monotonic. It is not onto, because $\bar f$ is not onto: the  range of $\bar f$ is $\;\mathbf R\smallsetminus\bigl\{\frac ac\bigr\}$. It ($f$) is not onto also because $\mathbf Q$ is not attained: if  $a,b,c,d$ are rational and $y=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is rational, $x=\frac{-dy+b}{cy-a}$ is rational too.

Comment: umm, what is a homographic function ?

Comment: A function defined by the type of  formula you wrote. It is an important notion in projective geometry. You can look at this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography).